# Rebinding Scroll Action After Ajax Call Interrupted by prettyLoader

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written your basic jQuery infinite scroll function. Expected behavior is consistent with the infinite scroll design pattern.

Upon completion of the ajax server call, I am rebinding the scroll event.

Everything works as expected for the first ajax call, however the scroll event is not being rebound for some reason. Adding in console data to debug the function shows that the code is executed through the end of setScrollingAction(), yet the scroll event does not take.

What am I missing?

```
// Function to make the ajax call, append the results and rebind the scroll event
function loadContent(opts) {
  $(opts.scrollTarget).unbind('scroll');
  $(opts.loaderObject).show();
  $.get($(opts.gridObject).attr('data-link'), function(data) {
    var $data = $(data);
    $(opts.gridObject).append($data.find(opts.appendObject));
    $(opts.loaderObject).hide();
    $(opts.gridObject).attr('data-link', $data.find(opts.gridObject).attr('data-link'));
    setScrollingAction(opts);
  });
};

// Function to set the loading action to the scroll event
function setScrollingAction(opts) {
  $(opts.scrollTarget).bind("scroll", function(event) {
    if (inLoadingRange(opts)) { loadContent(opts); }
  });
};

// Function to determine height from bottom of page
function inLoadingRange(opts) {
  var target = opts.scrollTarget;
  return ($(target).scrollTop()+opts.heightOffset >= $(document).height() - $(target).height());
};

// Fire it up
$(document).ready(function(){
  opts = {
    'scrollTarget': $(window),
    'loaderObject': "#loading",
    'gridObject'  : '#tileGrid',
    'appendObject': '.newItem',
    'heightOffset': 10
  };

  setScrollingAction(opts);
});
```

Comment: You're issue isn't reproducible. Here's a jsFiddle that emulates everything your doing http://jsfiddle.net/JLvmp/31/ if you scroll up and down on the page the DIV at the top will show different numbers and the event will be unbound and bound without issue. Perhaps you're using an old version of jQuery and should update?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a conflict with the [prettyLoader](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyloader/) plugin.

If you look through prettyLoader.js you will find the following function:

```
$.prettyLoader.hide = function() {
  $(document).unbind('click', $.prettyLoader.positionLoader);
  $(document).unbind('mousemove', $.prettyLoader.positionLoader);
  $(window).unbind('scroll');
  $('.prettyLoader').fadeOut(settings.animation_speed, function() { $(this).remove(); });
};
```

All scroll event assignments are being unbound on the third line of the function. Commenting out this line solved the problem, and did not have a noticeable effect of the loading image.

```
$.prettyLoader.hide = function() {
  $(document).unbind('click', $.prettyLoader.positionLoader);
  $(document).unbind('mousemove', $.prettyLoader.positionLoader);
  //$(window).unbind('scroll');
  $('.prettyLoader').fadeOut(settings.animation_speed, function() { $(this).remove(); });
};
```